# Post-processing YAML properties in Spring based on prefix to retrieve property from REST service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-properties, property-placeholder

I have a Spring boot configuration YAML with something like

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app
a: a literal
b: <<external due to special first and last chars>>
```

What i'm trying to do is to add some kind of resolver that will detect that the value of `b` is of the form `<<X>>` and will trigger retrieving that value from an external rest api to overwrite in memory the value that was in the YAML before it gets passed to the bean that holds the configurations at runtime

I tried and failed using an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` because I can't get ahold of the actual property values, just the property *sources*, so I can't post-process the values.

What currently works for me is in the `@Configuration` bean that holds the fields `a` and `b`, implement something in the setters to detect if the value that spring is trying to set starts with `<<` and ends with `>>` and if so, overwrite what gets loaded into the pojo with the version that i retrieve from the rest api. This is not ideal because I end up with a lot of duplication

What's the right way to implement something like this in Spring 5? I know spring properties support references to other properties using the syntax `${a}` so there must be some mechanism that already allows to add custom placeholder resolvers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing things a bit to mark the special properties. Then I created my own `PropertySource` kind of like @Andreas suggested. It was all inspired by `org.springframework.boot.env.RandomValuePropertySource`

The trick was changing the special chars `<<` and `>>` to the syntax used already by spring: `${}`, but like the random resolver which uses `${random.int`} I did something like `${rest.XXX}`. What I didn't know before is that by doing that, Spring will invoke all the property sources a second time with a new property name coming from the placeholder value (`rest.XXX` in my previous example). This way in the property source I can handle the value if the name of the property starts with my prefix `rest.`

Here is a simplified version of my solution

```
public class MyPropertySource extends PropertySource<RestTemplate> {
  private static final String PREFIX = "rest.";

  public MyPropertySource() {
    super(MyPropertySource.class.getSimpleName());
  }

  @Override
  public Object getProperty(@Nonnull String name) {
    String result = null;
    if (name.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        result = getValueFromRest(name.substring(PREFIX.length()));
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Finally, to register the property source I used an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` as [described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context). I couldn't find a simpler way that doesn't entail maintaining a new file `META-INF/spring.factories`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about *right* way, but one way to get properties from REST call is to implement your own [`PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html), that gets (and caches?) the values of specifically named properties.

Comment: I don't think this will work. not all properties in the file come from the REST api, only the ones with a special syntax in the value. What's more, some profiles might have the exact same property with a literal value, while another profile needs to be resolved externally, all based on the syntax of the value

Comment: *"not all properties in the file come from the REST api"* So? There is more than one active `PropertySource`, and the `Environment` will scan them until the property is found, so the custom `RestPropertySource` should only give values of properties sources from the REST web service. You will of course need to *configure* the `RestPropertySource` with which properties to get and which REST endpoint to use for that. whether to place the custom `RestPropertySource` first, last, or somewhere in the middle in the sequence of property sources, is of course entirely up to you.

Comment: my point is that whether to retrieve it from the `RestPropertySource` is a function of the *value* of the property, not the property name, so in the `RestPropertySource` i can't tell if it needs to be retrieved or not. I would need the regular yaml property source to load it first and then i could tell if it needs to be loaded from Rest, but it looks like spring stops looking for a source once one of them finds it. am i missing something?

Comment: But that's only if you're stuck on only one way of doing things, rather than entertain ideas of doing it slightly different. E.g. if the property is not explicitly given in the property file, you should give an alternative property for how to get the value. Like instead of defining `foo.bar = <<XYZ>>`, you would instead define `foo.bar.rest = XYZ`, and you'd place `RestPropertySource` last, so wny locally defined value of `foo.bar` would be applied, but if `RestPropertySource` is asked, then it would look for the `xxx.rest` value and would get the value from REST service is found.

Comment: In short, try thinking outside the box for a second.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an hacky solution I came up with using Spring Boot 2.1.5.
Probably better to use a custom [PropertyResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html)

Essentially it goes like:

1. Grab the `PropertySource` I care about. For this case it's `application.properties`. Applications can have `N` number of sources so if there are other places where `<< >>` can occur, then you'll to check them as well.
2. Loop through the source's values for `<< >>`
3. Dynamically replace the value if match.

My properties are:

```
a=hello from a
b=<<I need special attention>>
```

My hacked `ApplicationListener` is:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent;
import org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvironmentPrepareListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>, Ordered {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        // Only focused main application.properties (or yml) configuration
        // Loop through sources to figure out name
        final String propertySourceName = "applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]";
        PropertySource<?> propertySource = event.getEnvironment().getPropertySources()
                .get(propertySourceName);

        Map<String, Object> source = ((OriginTrackedMapPropertySource) propertySource).getSource();
        Map<String, Object> myUpdatedProps = new HashMap<>();
        final String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : source.entrySet()) {
            if (isDynamic(entry.getValue())) {
                String updatedValue = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class).getBody();
                myUpdatedProps.put(entry.getKey(), updatedValue);
            }
        }

        if (!myUpdatedProps.isEmpty()) {
            event.getEnvironment().getPropertySources()
                    .addBefore(
                            propertySourceName,
                            new MapPropertySource("myUpdatedProps", myUpdatedProps)
                    );
        }
    }

    private boolean isDynamic(Object value) {
        return StringUtils.startsWith(value.toString(), "<<")
                && StringUtils.endsWith(value.toString(), ">>");
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Hitting `/test` yields me:

```
{ "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem", "completed": false }
```

Comment: the problem i see, IIUC, is that you are requesting specifically properties `a` and `b`. That was exactly my problem with the `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, I couldn't find a way to loop through all the resolved properties looking for the ones of the form <<X>>. in other words, you depend on knowing the property name, not just the value, the same problem as Andreas' solution

Comment: I see you've figure it out, but I've updated my solution to reflect what you're asking.